# Display how much line A differs from line B as maximum

Tags: matlab

Working on a hobby project, I have a graph that I plot(A, B) various of times (using a script), sometimes only A exists which results in one line in the graph which is fine (when B is Nan).

`A` and `B` are of type matrix, both are `<1x100 double>`

What I want to do is to print out how much B exceeds A with the condition that B exceed A with <= 5. The printout can be written outside the graph, it doesn't matter how it is presented as long as I can read it (can be in the graph or outside). In the same time I want to get the average difference between A and B in total.

I would really appreciate the help, in this way I can see how things can be done in order to make more own stuff (i'm not good with tutorials).

[Example picture of how the graph looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Rm9E.gif)

Comment: Have you tried [subtracting `A` from `B`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/minus.html)? See also: [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1)

Comment: Yeah but I the thing is that the line is not always complete in cases where I have NaN values in some rows, therefore I really need to find that peak first.

Comment: So [`max`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html)?

Comment: Global or local maxima?

Comment: @patrik global maxima

Comment: ok, then you should try `max` as @excaza proposed.

Comment: @patrik how would you do for the average difference between A and B?

Comment: @J.Smith [nanmax](http://se.mathworks.com/help/stats/nanmax.html) or use [max](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) and ignore nan (found with `isnan`) in case you do not have statistics toolbox. You should at least try to look at the links other guys provide. In case you need someone to do your work you can probably find it online for a charge.